# mysql rounding result is unexpect after using average function

Tags: mysql, rounding

I am new to mysql and I was working on this problem on hacker rank as practice,
[The Blunder](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/the-blunder/problem).

For some reason my solution is wrong and with the help of an answer from the forum I narrowed the issue down this this step in the conversion process.

1. `select round(avg((CAST(replace(CAST(salary AS CHAR), '0', '') AS UNSIGNED)))), round(AVG(REPLACE(SALARY,'0',''))) from employees`;
2. `select avg((CAST(replace(CAST(salary AS CHAR), '0', '') AS UNSIGNED))), AVG(REPLACE(SALARY,'0','')) from employees;`

Before doing the rounding step, this is the result of the average for 1 and 2 respecitevly using the complier of hacker rank 1794.5000 1794.5.

And after the rounding here is the result of 1 and 2 respecitvely, 1795 1794.

I thought it was the way rounding works in mysql so I tried this query

```
select round(1794.5000), round (1794.5)
```

and the result is 1795 1795 as expected...

My Question is, why is the rounding for these 2 result done differently in the first 2 queries? One of them is rounded up and other ones yields the floor instead of round.